# Sound for dual monitors: software that will allow me to set sound streams 'per monitor' on windows

Tags: windows, audio, windows-10

I run a dual monitor setup, with displayport to each monitor. I also have a single pair of 2.0 speakers under one monitor. It feels a bit off when I have sound coming from one monitor, when there's a display on the other, and well, most modern monitors have some 'flavour' of sound output. Alternately USB sound cards are cheap.

So, this is what I need - a bit of software that monitors which window software is in, and sends audio accordingly.

```
+-------------------------+   +---------------------------+
|                         |   |                           |
|                         |   |                           |
|                         |   |                           |
|                         |   |                           |
|     Left                |   |    Right                  |
|                         |   |                           |
|                         |   |                           |
|                         |   |                           |
|                         |   |                           |
|                         |   |                           |
|                         |   |                           |
+-------------------------+   +---------------------------+
 +---+                +---+   +---+                   +---+
 | 1 |                | 2 |   | 3 |                   | 4 |
 +---+                +---+   +---+                   +---+
```

So. I want to have two sound devices A and B. A is connected to 1 and 2, B is connected to 3 and 4.

What would be nice would be to have any window totally on the left screen to output sound entirely to device A and have sound on 1 and 2, and any window on B to output to 3 and 4. "What about windows in the middle?" I don't particularly care. Sound on all 4 would be fine. Ideal behaviour would be to use 2 as the left channel and 3 as the right channel.

I'm *not* looking for the classic "centre/left/right" hardware setup. If sound's on one monitor I want it to behave like a single sound out. It might be nice to have somewhat finegrained control over when sound goes where, though the 'language' would need to be simple.

The environment is windows 10 (build 1511 if it matters). I'd prefer 'gratis' free software or something reasonably priced (so no 500 dollar software, something like 50USD would be my limit).